# Newsfeed remains empty

Tags: 2010, user-profile-service, server-farm

I am having a problem provisioning users newsfeeds with actual news. I have followed [Harbars guide](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx) to create the user profile server application. Also i have created the user profile Syncronisation application. Everything works without errors.

The problem i am having is that users newsfeeds do net get updated, I added a collegue, we both made some changes on the profile, put down some tags etc. But nothing shows up in the newsfeed.

Additional info

-Running on a server farm.

-When I start a full synchronisation with the active directory, no profiles get added! This while i selected an OU in AD with more than 30 user profiles. What i have read from the internet is that is not the way it should go, but i cannot find anyone that has the same issue.

-The timer job "User Profile Service Application - Activity Feed Job" is running and scheduled.

All comments and help are appreciated!

**edit** 
The [Sync log](http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/6272/synclog.png) looks like this and shows zero for each value on each item.

**edit2** 
The ULS logs do not show anny errors, they mostly repeat the following lines:

```
Updating SPPersistedObject UserProfileApplication Name=User Profile Service        Application. Version: 287083 Ensure: False, HashCode: 24603168, Id: c09b1681-77eb-4b33-8521-    e5d52b2f2737, Stack:    at     Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.BaseUpdate()     at     Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebServiceApplication.Update()     at         Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.Update()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.UpdateStatusHashtable(SynchronizationStatus status)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication.SynchronizeMIIS()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ILMProfileSynchronizationJob.Execute()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvokeInternal.Invoke(SPJobDefiniti...  037c45b3-919d-46d0-9d33-87a39666c81a
..on jd, Guid targetInstanceId, Boolean isTimerService, Int32& result)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvoke.Invoke(TimerJobExecuteData& data, Int32& result)     037c45b3-919d-46d0-9d33-87a39666c81a
Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job User Profile Service Application_ProfileSynchronizationJob). Execution Time=1860.52920133704 037c45b3-919d-46d0-9d33-87a39666c81a
Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-application-server-admin-service)   f7be0ecf-2307-45b6-bef9-6b54062f0864
```

Comment: If no profiles are being added, then there should be an error in the logs somewhere. Check your ULS logs, event logs, and the synchronization logs. Please post back any errors reported.

Comment: Can you try perhaps picking up a container further up the chain?  It would attempt to pull in additional OUs but you could at least see if it will pick up profiles.  If it is not picking up anything I am wondering if the connection might be an issue.

Comment: In the connection creation menu, i can select OUs and users etc. I picked a OU that contains over 30 users and also some computers and groups. So it is able to read the AD from the used user account, and it has a connection to the AD.. do you think it has to have additional rights on the AD server to be able to read the users? Or what do you think can be an issue with the connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oke so this was very dumb, it turns out i had to tick the "Enable news feed on My Sites" box, in the "Setup My Sites" Menu in the user profile serve application. Now all the newsfeeds work!

The problem with the sync from Active Directory not working was due to the account used to get the information. We used a standard account to do this, and we were able to browse AD with it so I assumed that it would work in the SharePoint sync. This is not the case, because when running the sync under the domain admin account everything was working splendid!

Hope this helps anyone in the future.

Comment: "Enable news feed on My Sites" was exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

The most common mistake is that the timer job is not running. I think its the "User Profile Service Application - Activity Feed Job" you can activate it unter http://yourCA/_admin/ServiceJobDefinitions.aspx

Comment: Sorry the job is running and scheduled to run every hour. I also mannually started it so this is not the problem. I will add it to the main post.